# I need the top x most recent (by SALEDT) rows grouped be neighborhood (NBHD)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using microsoft access and I need a sql query to return the top x (40 in my case) most recent sales for each neighborhood (`NBHD`). My data looks something like this:

```
PARID      PRICE     SALEDT      SALEVAL  NBHD
 04021000   140000    1/29/2016   11       700
 04021000   160000    2/16/2016   11       700
 04018470   250000    4/23/2015   08       701
 04018470   300000    4/23/2015   08       701
 04016180   40000     5/9/2017    11       705
 04023430   600000    6/12/2017   19       700
```

And what I need is the top 40 most recent `SALEDT` entries for each `NBHD`, and if the same `PARID` would show up in that top 40 twice or more, I only want the most recent one. If the rows have the same `PARID` and the same `SALEDT`, I need the only most expensive one. For this small set of sample data, I would get:

```
 PARID      PRICE     SALEDT      SALEVAL  NBHD
 04021000   160000    2/16/2016   11       700
 04023430   600000    6/12/2017   19       700
 04018470   300000    4/23/2015   08       701
 04016180   40000     5/9/2017    11       705
```

I get row 2 (as it has a later `SALEDT` than row 1), row 4 (as it has a higher `PRICE` than row 3, and row 5 and row 6. Hopefully that is clear. Also, I'm using MS access SQL to do this, but wouldn't be opposed to some VBA solution if that is easier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you can do the following to get the 40 most recent entries for each neighborhood:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.salesdt in (select top 40 t2.salesdt
                    from t as t2
                    where t2.nbhd = t.nbhd
                    order by t2.salesdt desc
                   );
```

Your additional constraints are rather confusing.  I'm not sure I fully follow them because I don't know what the columns really refer to.

Comment: PARID is an ID number that refers to a specific parcel of land. SALEDT is the date that parcel was sold, PRICE is the price of the sale, SALEVAL is the classification of the kind of sale and isn't relevant to the query. and NBHD is the neighborhood that the parcel resides in. I need the top 40 most recent sales per neighborhood, with no duplicate PARIDs in them. If a duplicate parid shows up, I want the most recent of the two. If the duplicate parid has the same sale date, I want the most expensive of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 select a.parid, max(a.price)price, a.saledt, a.saleval, a.nbhd from #table a join (
 select parid,  max(saledt) saledt from  #table
 group by  parid ) b on a.parid=b.parid and a.saledt=b.saledt  
 group by a.parid,  a.saledt, a.saleval, a.nbhd
 order by a.nbhd
```